# Changing Role Claims to logged in user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, roles

I'm using Identity server and I wanna create an application like discord or slack. Basically you can be part of multiple organizations, but you have a different role in each of them. So when you click on the role I wanna create an access token with the role claims that correspond to your role on the organization. Basically, I am asking for a way to manually call my profile service, so I can always create the corresponding access_token

Answer (score 0):

> I am asking for a way to manually call my profile service, so I can always create the corresponding access_token

You can add your custom ProfileService for IdentityServer, here is steps to follow:

1. Add your custom ProfileService which implements `IdentityServer4.Services.IProfileService`. This class is added on IdentityServer project.

```
public class CustomProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        
    }
```

Checkout [ProfileService](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/AspNetIdentity/src/ProfileService.cs) to get an idea for implementation details. And [here](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow/blob/master/src/StsServerIdentity/IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService.cs) is a very good example to follow.

2. Add it to IOC on Startup class of IdentityServer project

```
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, CustomProfileService>();
```

3. Set it as profile service used on IdentityServer - This code is on Startup class of IdentityServer

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>();
```

Read more [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html?highlight=profile)